# How to authenticate bearer-only client with public client in keycloak?

Tags: authentication, oauth, keycloak

I have two clients.

1)Front-End Client:
Access Type:Public

2)Back-End Client:
Access Type:Bearer

How do I authenticate Back-End Client with the access token of Front-End Client and How do I access the resource of back-end client?

How is the trust between the clients work?

Thank You